# ACF retrieving checkbox value from a Taxonomy (category) page

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

With ACF I understand how to retrieve the checkbox values from a page but unclear from a taxonomy page, here is what I have so far

I have a new ACF which adds a checkboxes called "location"

```
ACF Field Name = "location"
Choices = 
zone1 : Zone 1
zone2 : Zone 2
zone3 : Zone 3
zone4 : Zone 4
```

**this is my current code which displays the zone name**

```
    <div class="selection">
    <?php
        $lines = get_terms( array(
            'taxonomy' => 'zone_line',
            'hierarchical' => true,
            'parent' => 0,
            'hide_empty' => True,
        ) );

        foreach( $lines as $line ):
    ?>


<!-- //start: only show if checkbox zone1 is check -->    
    <a href="<?php echo esc_attr( Center()->link_res_line( $line ) ); ?>">
<?php echo $line->name; ?><span class="fa fa-chevron-right">&nbsp;</span></a>
<!-- //end -->    

        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </div>
```

[image: CF settings]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get an ACF field value from a taxonomy term, you need to specify the taxonomy name and the id of the term instead of just an id:

```
get_field( 'field_name', 'taxonomyname_' . term_term_id )
```

In your case, you would do this:

```
get_field( 'location', 'zone_line_' . $line->term_id );
```

Or you can pass the `WP_Term` Object:

```
get_field( 'location', $line );
```

#### EDIT

If you need to test for just `zone1`:

```
<div class="selection">
    <?php
    $lines = get_terms( [
        'taxonomy'     => 'zone_line',
        // Added false to hide_empty in case no posts have this term
        'hide_empty'   => FALSE,
    ] );

    foreach ( $lines as $line ):
        $zone = get_field( 'location', $line );

        if ( in_array('zone1', $zone, true ) ) :
            ?>

            <a href="<?php echo esc_attr( Center()->link_res_line( $line ) ); ?>">
                <?php echo $line->name; ?><span class="fa fa-chevron-right">&nbsp;</span></a>

        <?php endif; ?>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</div>

I tested this in my environment and it works as expected.
```

Comment: so I would fo something like this `<?php 
get_field( 'location', 'zone_line_' . $line->term_id );
if( $line->term_id && in_array('zone1', $line->term_id) ): ?>
// <a href....link
<?php endif; ?>`

Comment: You don't need all those checks. Updated answer.

Comment: It does not seem to be detecting if the checkbox is checked for zone1 ...How would you recommended troubleshooting this?

Comment: Edit your question with the output of `$lines`. Do a var_dump() before the foreach loop and see what you are getting. Starting from the top, we can start to see where the data breakdown is.

Comment: OH! Are you allowing more than one checkbox to be selected? So can, "Zone 1" and another Zone be checked? If so, then we may need the in_array(); Updated answer to support in_array()

Comment: Also, do a var_dump() of `$zone` right before the `if` statement

Comment: I added the changes as well as a var_dump which returned `NULL`.... I also added some screenshots of my ACF settings

Comment: In your screenshot, the taxonomy name says "Line" is that the actual taxonomy and not "zone_line"?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/212861/discussion-between-disinfor-and-acctman).